# Allowing passing a function as an argument with an optional kwarg in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that takes in another function as a parameter, and then runs it when a condition is met. However, some of the function passed in will have a keyword argument, and if it is present, I want it to be filled. This should also work with `threading`, so try/except is not an option here. Here is an example of what I am talking about.

```
def runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(func, thread = False):
  larger = False
  while not larger:
    num = int(input("Enter a number"))
    larger = (num > 10)

  kwargnumpresentinfunc = # I don't know what to put here
  
  if shouldthread:
    if kwargpresentinfunc:
      thread = threading.Thread(target=func, kwargs={"num": num})
      thread.start()
    else:
      thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
      thread.start()

  else:
    if kwargpresentinfunc:
      func(num=num)
    else:
      func()

def customDisplayFunc(num = None):
  print(f"Num {num} is greater than 10!")

def customDisplayFunc1()
  print("Num larger than 10!")

runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc, thread = True) # kwargnumpresentinfunc = True
runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc1) # kwargnumpresentinfunc = False
```

How would I work out `kwargnumpresentinfunc?` I thought about using `inspect`, however the function passed in to `runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen` may also be an inbuilt function, and `inspect.getfullargspec(func)` doesn't work for inbuilts. If this is bad practice, I am open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(func, *args, **kwargs):
  larger = False
  while not larger:
    num = int(input("Enter a number"))
    larger = (num > 10)
  
  if kwargs.get("shouldthread", False):
    if kwargs.get("num") and isinstance(kwargs.get("num"), int):
      thread = threading.Thread(target=func, kwargs={"num": num})
      thread.start()
    else:
      thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
      thread.start()
  else:
    if kwargs.get("num"):
      func(num=num)
    else:
      func()

def customDisplayFunc(num = None):
  print(f"Num {num} is greater than 10!")

def customDisplayFunc1()
  print("Num larger than 10!")
```

and run it

```
runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc, shouldthread=True)
runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc, shouldthread=True, num=4)
runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc1, num=5)
runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc1)
```

Comment: I don't want to have to explicitly say that num should be passed in to the function, it should automatically detect it based on the kwargs of the function passed in.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution that works for my cases, and doesn't require explicit keyword passing in. I replaced `kwargnumpresentinfunc = # I don't know what to put here` with:

```
kwargnumpresentinfunc = False
try:
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    if "num" in sig.parameters:
        kwargnumpresentinfunc = True
except ValueError:
    pass
```

This works by attempting to get the signature of the function and checking if "num" is part of it, which works for non-inbuilt functions. The except ValueError means that if I come across an inbuilt, it gracefully handles it and assumes that the keyword argument "num" is not present. Full code:

```
def runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(func, thread = False):
  larger = False
  while not larger:
    num = int(input("Enter a number"))
    larger = (num > 10)

  kwargnumpresentinfunc = False
  try:
      sig = inspect.signature(func)
      if "num" in sig.parameters:
          kwargnumpresentinfunc = True
  except ValueError:
      pass
  
  if shouldthread:
    if kwargpresentinfunc:
      thread = threading.Thread(target=func, kwargs={"num": num})
      thread.start()
    else:
      thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
      thread.start()

  else:
    if kwargpresentinfunc:
      func(num=num)
    else:
      func()

def customDisplayFunc(num = None):
  print(f"Num {num} is greater than 10!")

def customDisplayFunc1()
  print("Num larger than 10!")

runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc, thread = True) # kwargnumpresentinfunc = True
runFuncOnNumLargerThanTen(customDisplayFunc1) # kwargnumpresentinfunc = False
```